# parsing json from a file in go

Tags: json, go

config.json

```
{
    "admins": [
        "AdminA",
        "AdminB"
    ],
    "apikey": "apikey"
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type MainConfiguration struct {
    admins []string `json:"admins"`
    apikey string `json:"apikey"`
}

func ParseConf() *MainConfiguration {
    f, _ := os.Open("config.json")
    defer f.Close()
    d := json.NewDecoder(f)
    m := &MainConfiguration{}
    d.Decode(m)
    return m
}

func main() {
    conf := ParseConf()
    fmt.Printf("%s", conf)
}
```

After looking for everything I could to fix this all I get is:

&{[] }

Whats wrong here, and why is this empty? Its basic and I've basically just copy/pasted from elsewhere and while this may be common, I'm not finding answers to this specific question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make fields in MainConfiguration public (note first capital letter):

```
type MainConfiguration struct {
    Admins []string `json:"admins"`
    Apikey string `json:"apikey"`
}
```

Comment: I knew it would be something stupid I'm overlooking due to not working with Go 24/7.